# Using Different content sources for search in different web applications

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, enterprise-search, result-source, content-source

I have 3 content sources defined in my search application, I have two web applications.

I want content source 1 and 2 to be shown in search results for webapp1

Content source 1 and 3 to be shown in search results for webapp2

I could define content sources in CA, but I couldn't find a way to achieve the desirable.

Is there any way possible to get this done.

I know I can use different search applications for this, but is there a way to do this with the same search app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SharePoint version is not specified, I am assuming it to be SP 2013. You can modify the Search Results web part on the search page to restrict the results based on the content source. Edit the Search results web part and Click on "Change Query". In the Query Text box, use your two content sources, example:

```
ContentSource:"Your Content Source 1" OR ContentSource:"CS 2"
```

[image: Example]